# Bash while read input issue

Tags: bash

An possible way to use while read is:

`while read server application date; do ..`

So now i could print only the applications, i understand that. So here comes my question:
with my example i know exactly how many "arrays" there are but how would i do it if i dont know how many "arrays" exist per line?
Example file:

```
Server : ID1 ; ID2 ; ID3
Server : ID1
Server : ID1 ; ID2
Server : ID1 ; ID2 ; ID3 ; ID4
```

It doesnt have to be with read but how could i read them so i could  for example

`echo "$Server $ID3"`

p.s sorry for the bad english

so what i am doing so far is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
csv=$2

echo Server : Applikation : AO : BV : SO > endlist.txt
while read server aid; do
grep $aid $csv | while IFS=";" read id aid2 name alia status typ beschreibung gesch gesch2 finanzierung internet service servicemodell AO BV SO it betrieb hersteller; do
if [[ $aid == $aid2 ]]
then
echo $server : $name : $AO : $BV : $SO >> endlist.txt
fi
done
done < $file
```

the Problem is that the first while read is for now only SERVER and AID but i want to edit this file so more than one AID is possible

Comment: What do you mean by "print only the applications"? How is an "array" defined within your input file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add all clarification to the question itself by editing it. Don't use the comment section for this

Comment: `while read server aid; do
grep $aid $csv |` looks strange and I don't think it does what you think it does. I don't understand `if [[ $aid == $aid2 ]]` - if you are filtering with grep, why then filter with `if`? Just do it in `grep`. It looks like you want to just `cut` the file to extract some parts. Also you output `:` between those `$AO` `$BV`...  The script seems to be unrelated to the question you asked.

Comment: pluse-uno for a pretty good beginners' Q. You even included some code! Good show.! In the future, please include the required output from your sample input. It makes it much easier to understand your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It doesnt have to be with read but how could i read them so i could for example
>
> ```
> echo "$Server $ID3"
> ```

First split the input on `:`, then read the array on `;`. Use bash arrays and `read -a` to save input to an array.

```
# split the input on `:` and spaces
while IFS=' :' read -r server temp_ids; do
     # split the ids on `;` and spaces into an array
     IFS=' ;' read -r -a id <<<"$temp_ids"

     # check if there are at least 3 elements
     if ((${#id[@]} >= 3)); then
         # array numbering starts from 0
         echo "$server ${id[2]}"
     else
         echo There is no 3rd element...
     fi

done <<EOF
Server : ID1 ; ID2 ; ID3
Server : ID1
Server : ID1 ; ID2
Server : ID1 ; ID2 ; ID3 ; ID4
EOF
```

will output:

```
Server ID3
There is no 3rd element...
There is no 3rd element...
Server ID3
```